Charge EV from array of small solar panels DC/AC
Suppose I have 20 solar panels specified to yield 18V, 40-80W.
What would be the best (most efficient, non-damaging) way to use this to charge an EV, if possible?
Note that it doesn't matter for me that the charging time might be very long.
The details I am interested in is specifically:

Configuration of panels in series/parallel
Use of AC or DC
Voltage / Amps distribution in output
Extra equipment, like inverters voltage regulators etc.

It seems like it's required to use AC for this kind of slow charging, but I don't understand why (couldn't I skip the DC-to-AC conversion and its loss?)
For example when the regenerative breaking system is activated while driving, this is presumably DC but probably way lower power than DC fast-chargers..
BTW the car I am going to try this on is the
Maxus Euniq 5.
So if you want to get specific, it would be a good example.

AC input to a standard EV charging port, IF they will tolerate such a low power level, requires least playing with the system.  Access to the high voltage battery may be more efficient but is difficult, potentially (pun noted) dangerous, and as you are operating "behind the battery managers back" risks unexpected secondary consequences.

IDK about your car, but for my car, the only way that slow charging would be possible is if I designed a battery charger that bypassed the car's built-in electronics, and connected directly to the high-voltage battery. My car's built-in battery charger connects to mains power through a J1772 connector. When I plug it in at home, the car will draw 16A at 240V. And, (I'm guessing) if the mains can't supply that amount of current at that voltage, then the charger simply will shut down.

Note that AC EV charging (IEC 61851) has a minimum required charging current of 6 A per phase. Depending on the local mains voltage, this translates to about 660 W in the US (or higher, depending on where you live and if you're charging with single or 3-phase). The EVSE will negotiate a higher current with the EV when it's available, but will not allow charging at less than 660 W. Your solar panels need to supply at least this minimum current for effective AC charging.

@StarCat -- The OP has stated 20 panels of 40W to 80W, so 800W to 1,600W, so the 660W minimum you're worried about should be met.

@MicroservicesOnDDD, yes,but probably for just a small part of the day. Now OP did state that it did not matter how long the charging time was, but the average EV would need many days to charge from, say, 20% to 80% SoC at those speeds.

The most promising way so far in terms of price and yield I reckon is to use an inverter to mimic a granny lead. So I have found a cheap 36V (DC) -> 240V (AC) inverter claiming to yield a pure sine wave output and capable of handling up to 2kW input.
Assuming the yield of each solar panel is 54W (18V, 3A), the connection from solar power to car battery becomes:
Solar radiation
-> ( 2 x 18V, 50W solar panel in series ) x 10 in parallel (36V, 30A, DC)
-> Inverter (240V, 4.5A, AC)
-> Granny lead
-> Car
I bought a multimeter and oscilloscope to check that all components work as they are sold. Unless someone can dissuade me, or provide a better alternative, I am going to try this.

If

Note that it doesn't matter for me that the charging time might be very long.

then
it doesn't really matter too much how efficient it is.
The choice of going through AC or DC additional equipment to get from panels to EV will mainly be down to convenience, what equipment is readily available.
That said, if you have fewer conversion stages, you ought to be able to obtain lower losses, so higher efficiency. Ideally then, a single stage DC to DC converter would be your most efficient choice, if it was available, or if you could design and build it. The next most efficient choice is anything you can get your hands on, whether it goes via AC or DC intermediate stages.

Thanks for your answer. I would argue that efficiency still matters, I mainly wrote that sentence because many in here seem to think charging time of >3 days is beyond any practical purpose. I do care if its 5 or 10 days though. I would also love a bit more details like rough sketch of the circuit if we go with the - say DC->AC conversion, since it seems easiest to get to work with the internals of the EV, cheers

Electric vehicles don't support low voltage DC charging because there is little demand for it.  The standard is either household AC, or high voltage and high current DC.
The simplest option would be to buy equipment normally intended for off-grid living:

An MPPT battery charger to take power from the panels
A low voltage battery bank (12 to 48V), to match the charger.
A pure sine wave inverter, powerful enough to charge the car.

You would need to configure your car charger to run at quite a low power, or use a "granny lead" intended to plug into a normal household socket.  When charging a car, it's the car charger that tells the car how much power it is allowed to draw.

"Little demand for it" - That's a fair answer. It would be nice to know if that's the only reason, or if there's also some physical and/or battery technical reasons. It would also be helpful with a guide how to make the charger 'tell' the car the right thing then (or a link to such)

Car batteries run at rather high voltages.  Mine uses 400V.  400V DC is dangerous: it can arc badly and electrocute you instantly.  So to be safe, the car would need a socket that could take a variable safe low voltage and step it up to 400V.  Since most people don't have a pile of solar panels to use, the car manufacturers aren't going to spend money on an extra charging circuit that most people would never use.  Most people with 20 solar panels would put them on the roof and either buy a grid-tied inverter, or get a big battery bank.
